# JCalendar Focus Event

Tags: java, jcalendar, jdatechooser

I use [JCalendar](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/index.html)'s `JDateChooser` in a table date column as a `tablecelleditor`. The problem is that when the column cell clicked `JDateChooser` appears but if it loses its focus it does not fire focus lost event. How to make it fire focus lost event? And after doing this is there any way to prevent its firing focus lost when `JCalendar` appeared after clicking the `JCalendar` Button?

The thing I try to do is if some one specify a date by selecting a date from the calendar `stopCellEditing();` Else wait until focus lost event to stop or `cancelCellEditing();`

[image]

Comment: as I know with JCalendar is there included TableEditor/Renderer too

Comment: are you using JCalendar from jar, or from Source Files, if from jar, then download source File (JCalendarCellEditor.java)

Comment: i use jar and found the class. Should i still download the source file?

Comment: check before if you are able to use this class, I think that there any difference betweens plain java file and class

Comment: It is a very simple CellEditor :/

I need something like JDateChooser.addDateSelectionListener(
    public void dateSelected(DateEvent evt){
        ...
    }
);

Comment: And focus event of jDateChooser get work

Comment: @mKorbel is correct, there's a working `TableCellEditor` in the source distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a `propertyChanged` event in `JDateChooser` which is fired when a date selected. And `jTable1.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", true);` make the table terminate edit on focusLost

Edit : When calendar popup is down if you want to change the year that make table cell lose focus and terminateEditing :(

```
jDateChooser.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getPropertyName().equals("date")) {
            stopCellEditing();
        }
    }
});
```

Edit(Solved) : Instead of using `jTable1.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", true);` adding ta `FocusListener` to `JTable` in `TableCellEditor` and cancel editing when focus lost give a chance to check if the `JDateChooser's` popup is visible or not. But before this, `JDateChooser` should be extended with a popup `isVisible` method. Because popup variable is protected. And cell editor components should not be focusable else `JTable` also loses its focus

Answer (score 1):

In the [source distribution](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/) mentioned by @mKorbel, `com.toedter.calendar.demo.DemoTable` is an example that uses `com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooserCellEditor` as a cell editor. The essential steps are these.

```
JTable table = new JTable(…);
table.setDefaultEditor(Date.class, new JDateChooserCellEditor());
```

Addendum: Here is an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows the expected behavior.

```
import com.toedter.calendar.demo.DemoTable;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643893 */
public class CalendarTable {

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("CalendarTable");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new DemoTable());
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new CalendarTable().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way i found a propertyChanged event when date is changed in JDateChooser. Now i just need make JDateChooser fire focusLost

Comment: I can't reproduce the effect you describe using `JDateChooserCellEditor`; an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) might shed some light.

Comment: it should be a normal behaviour of table cell editor. Table cell editor should cancelCellEditing when focus lost, and stop cell editing when editing finished. So when someone selects a date it should stop the cell editing. This can be done by propertyChanged event. But when cell editor lost focus such as when i change the tab which cell editor's table is contained cell editor dont cancel cell editing

Comment: and jTable1.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", true); fixes it